# Is there a way to use html/javascript/php to convert webpage to pdf and email it in background of wordpress site?

Tags: javascript, php, html, email, pdf

I'm using wordpress and want to convert the page into a pdf file. I want this to be done in the background and I want to be able to send it as an attachment using wp_mail. Here is the code that I am using to email:

```
[insert_php]
$to = "myaddress@example.com";
$subject = "Subject Line Here";
$content = "Content of email";
$status = wp_mail($to, $subject, $content);
[/insert_php]
```

How would I convert the webpage to pdf and attach it above. I want it all in the background so the user doesn't see anything and doesn't have to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

This project converts HTML to PDF: [WKHTML2PDF](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/). It is a single file executable. The result of this conversion can be mailed with WordPress with the wp_mail function.

Comment: Do you know if it takes the current webpage being displayed and turns it into a pdf? The webpage that I am working on takes variables and data from another page and puts it into graphs using amcharts.

Comment: It is a command line tool and it does not need to actually be on the screen.